# Calculate areas of different land uses from a shapefile within a raster cell

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, area

Datasets: [Data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KdVdwzXDXzeC43fsvyNvgAtxxEWgC32O?usp=sharing)

I am working with a raster dataset of air pollution data on a 0.1 x 0.1 degree regular grid. I also have a shapefile containing categorical data for different land uses.

I'm trying to develop a relationship between land use and air pollution, and in order to do that, I need to calculate the different area of land use within each raster cell in R.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have included the shapefile and the netcdf I'm working with in the link above.

Comment: I would make the question more specific and give reproducible example if necessary.

Comment: Your link online provides me with the netCDF file

Comment: Link has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *minimal self-contained, reproducible example*.

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
pol <- rast(f)
names(pol) <- "pollution"

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v$landuse <- c("a", "b", "c")
lu <- aggregate(v, "landuse")
```

Solution

```
e <- extract(pol, lu, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)

cbind(landuse=lu$landuse, e[,2,drop=F])
#  landuse pollution
#1       a  370.1575
#2       b  341.3008
#3       c  336.7545
```

However, it is odd to have land use as polygons, you would expect that to be a raster; and that would work better if it is a large dataset.